# Defacto template application in Python

Tags: python, c, unit-testing, templates

Is there a defacto template application for Python?

I am trying to auto generate C code for use in unit tests from python

My original approach using print statements is very clunky and error prone

It struck me that a template application such as those used in web app development might be a more elegant solution

My initial research seems to suggest Cheetah is a good option, however there seem to be many potential options

My requirements would be that it is reliable and simple - would Cheetah represent 'best practice' for this sort of application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While there are many standalone and powerful template engines in Python there is one in Python standard library.

There is [Template](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#template-strings) class in string module that implements [PEP 292 "Simpler String Substitutions"](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0292/) that is very easy to learn and use. Personally I prefer to use this in my unit tests.

Comment: I think this is the simplest and best solution for my C auto-generation needs (for now...)

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there's such a thing as a *defacto* templating system for Python, there's quite a wide variety of them.

Personally, I haven't tried out Cheetah yet, but had some very successful experiences with [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/), and there's also alot of buzz around [Mako](http://www.makotemplates.org/). Both of these are more focused on generating HTML code, but there's really no impediment on using them for anything else. 
I would go with the one that provides the most comfortable syntax for what you're used to.

Comment: @Hiett it is just a first impression. They use three different tag styles for different tags: `<% foo 'bar' %>`, `% foo bar`, `$(foo(bar))`.

Comment: @Hiett if you are asking about tag styles in Mako then you need to know that you cannot choose. Every tag must use its own style.

If you question was about template engine I would answer that I'm using different engines for different tasks. Django (they have its own Jinja like template engine) for usual web projects. Mako for advanced non Django web projects. string.Template (as in my answer) in unit tests where it is better to depend on fewer external libraries.

Comment: actually the mako documentation isn't very good, too few examples - e.g. how do you push variables into a context?

Comment: @Hiett here http://www.makotemplates.org/docs/usage.html#using-templatelookup `**kwargs` in second example is the context.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5849/discussion-between-lig-and-hiett)